# Looking for different way to write condition composed by an object type Integer or Double

Tags: java

I am looking for a best practice or best way to write my if condition below: (Integer)fRes < (Integer) bRes

fRes and bRes can be both Integer at the same time or Integer as well.
In my code below, it works only if both fRes and bRes are Integer but if both are Double, it throws a classcast exception
Note that this code is located in a for loop
Thanks

```
if (!isCalculableData() && (fRes == null || (Integer)fRes < (Integer) bRes)) {
   //do stuff
} else if (bRes instanceof Double && list1.contains(optCodes.get(i))) {
  // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting at all?

Comment: how did you initialize the both `bRes` and `fRes` variables?

Comment: Both variables bRes and fRes are returned by two different methods executed just before the if condition. I want to write something like this: boolean condition = getWriteCondition(Object fRes , Object bRes); public boolean getWriteCondition(Object fRes , Object bRes) { if (bfRes Res instanceof Double && bRes instanceof Double) return (Double )fRes < (Double ) bRes; else if (bfRes Res instanceof Integer && bRes instanceof Integer) return (Integer)fRes < (Integer) bRes;

Answer (score 0):

If your variables were declared using the Integer Class, try the following to see if it works.

`if ( !isCalculableData() && ( fRes == null || fRes.intValue() < bRes.intValue() ) ) {
       //do stuff
    } else if ( bRes instanceof Double && list1.contains( optCodes.get( i ) ) ) {
      // do other stuff
    }` 
It should also work with the Double Class as well.

Comment: Thank you but can you explain why this: (Integer)fRes < (Integer) bRes) throws an exception and not the new one you give to me above: fRes.intValue() < bRes.intValue() in case fRes and bRes are Double ??? I just want to understand. Thanks

Comment: Because if a Double is returned as you stated, you are trying to downcast from a Double to an Integer which will always throw an exception. Most numerical classes, on the other hand, contain methods to accomplish this. For example, the Integer class has a method know as the doubleValue() as well as the same intValue method. You can check the java docs on these classes to get a better understanding.